# What do the humanoid classes in Star Trek mean?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

I have been watching Star Trek: Voyager for the last few days and they have been categorizing humanoids by class. So far, I heard of class three and class five.

I checked on Memory Alpha and [the available information on that topic is ludicrous](http://memory-alpha.org/wiki/Class_5_humanoid):

> Class 5 humanoid is a humanoid categorization class used by B'Elanna Torres to categorize the Vhnori decaying bodies found on an asteroid around a planet on stardate 48623.5 (2371).

Yes. That's really everything.

Does anyone have an idea what each of those humanoid classes mean?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no canon or licensed work that discusses the humanoid class system except for the brief mention by B'Elanna Torres you cited. You can consider it minor technobabble used to make Torres's dialogue [sound more technical](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGAahDeceHI).

Comment: This is entirely correct.  And she needed all the help she could get, considering she literally couldn't identify feces without a tricorder.

Answer (score 4):

"*Class 3 humanoid*" was another Starfleet classification for certain types of humanoids. The Vidiians, for example, were described thusly in [VOY: Phage](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/104.htm)

> **JANEWAY:** *Did you find any evidence of the life sign that Neelix reported?*
>
> **CHAKOTAY:** *No.*
>
> **KIM:** *Captain, I've analysed the sensor logs from Neelix's tricorder. The bio-scanner picked up a single **class three humanoid
>   organism.***

Comment: Can you link the google page?

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Humanoid#Taxonomy_of_humanoids

Comment: @bleh - Easy peasy.

Answer (score 0):

Humanoid classes probably refer to closest matches the Federation has on record and differentiate between humanoids based on their physiological aspects.

The tricorder scans humanoids and likely looks for closest matches. If the internal biology matches to what they have on record then they have an easier time understanding their biology in order to provide medical treatments, evolutionary patterns, etc.

The federation is comprised of over 150 alien species... And has explored 11% of the milky way by early TNG (this % would likely be higher by the time voyager launched).

So it stands to reason the federation has extensive medical information on a variety of different species.

Humans and vulcans might not be considered the same class of humanoids due to differences in strength (vulcans have 3x higher strength thhan humans) and green blood.
Cardassians for example would likely be a different class as well. 
Romulans and vulcans would likely be in the same humanoid category due to common ancestry.

Comment: You have some good information but could you please include links to your sources? Research is the key to a good answer. I think most of what you show could be found on  [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Portal:Main)